# Is it possible to leave some of files unminified (for use the in runtime) when optimizing with r.js?

Tags: requirejs, optimization

In my project i have  file 'settings.js' which i want to leave unminified because i want user to be able to change it.
 is it possible to minify all the files but this and use them together?
here is my build profile(i tried to use excludeShallow but no luck):

```
({
  appDir: '../',
  baseUrl: 'js',
  dir: 'dist',
  name: 'config',
  skipDirOptimize:true,
  fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/,
  excludeShallow: '../js/settings.js',
  mainConfigFile: '../js/config.js',
  optimizeCss: 'standard',
  removeCombined: true,
  deps:["config","app"],
  paths: {
    'jquery'    : 'jquery/jquery',        
    'jquerymobile.config' : 'mobile/jquerymobile.config',
    'jquerymobile': 'mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min' ,
    'underscore': 'underscore-amd/underscore-min',
    'backbone'  : 'backbone-amd/backbone-min',
    text: 'plugins/text'
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    'jquery'    : 'jquery',
    'jquerymobile.config' : ['jquery'],
     jquerymobile : {
          deps : ["jquery", 'jquerymobile.config']
     },
     backbone: {
          deps: ['underscore', 'jquery', 'jquerymobile'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
     }

  }
})
```

Thanks forawrd

Comment: Shouldn't `excludeShallow` take the module name, instead of the JS file name? I.e. try without the `.js` suffix and also try to exclude the module as you would `require()` it; in your case I would try `excludeShallow: 'settings'`, since `baseUrl:'js'`.

Answer (score 0):

The fix it to put module name, instead of filename :

```
excludeShallow: ['settings']
```